# How to implement a class of sr-only when a class already exists

Tags: css, accessibility

I have a div with an already established class that I cannot remove but I need to for both visual readers and the screen reader to be able to "read" the contents. As I understand it, `sr-only` is for the screen reader to only be able to read, how do I develop this for both screen readers and visual readers?

```
<div class="page instructions">
  <p>I'm baby pBR&B activated charcoal mlkshk quinoa, kickstarter keytar tattooed bespoke cray 8-bit ramps blue bottle.</p>
  <p>Cliche cronut hella actually godard venmo banh mi hashtag paleo poutine selvage fixie.</p>
  <p>Locavore tofu sartorial man braid, pickled tumeric pug bespoke schlitz adaptogen live-edge microdosing echo park cronut.</p>
  <p>Art party ramps direct trade, hashtag heirloom gluten-free literally glossier vaporware sartorial normcore edison bulb tousled.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `sr-only` implies that it should _only_ be accessible to screen readers, and _not_ visible to sighted users viewing the text visually. Is this your intention?

Comment: @LionelRowe, ahh only, right that makes sense. Okay so no, my intent is that both visual readers and the screen reader can both "read" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the text visible to *both* screen readers *and* sighted users viewing the text visually, there is no further action required. Assuming the text is viewable on screen, it will already be viewable to screen readers by default.

---

Note that `class="page instructions"` means the element has the class of `page` and the class of `instructions` (class names are space delimited). So if, for example, you wanted text to have classes `sr-only` and `page-instructions`, you would simply use `class="sr-only page-instructions"`.

Comment: ahh so it will be viewable by screen reader as long as the text is physically rendered on the screen, thank you.

Comment: Yep. The only cases in which text is hidden from screen readers are if the `aria-hidden` attribute is deliberately added, or if the text is rendered using an image or a CSS `::before` or `::after` content.